# Writing data to Firebase can only work after just signed in, not working successfully unless signed out and sign in again

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I’m writing data to Firebase on Android. The writing process can work well after the user has been just signed in successfully. I can see the data have been updated on my console and the CompletionListener triggered well accordingly. However, after the APP performs the writing for several times while the same user stays signed-in, somehow it fails to work unless the user signed out and sign in again. I can’t see my data on the console nor get CompletionListener triggered in my APP. 
Here is my code of the writing process:

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){

        public void run(){
            for(int  i = 0 ; i < dataBufferList.size();++i){


                myRef.push().setValue(dataBufferList.get(i), new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference dataRef) {

                        if (databaseError != null) {
                            System.out.println("Data saved : error " + databaseError.getMessage());
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Data saved successfully.");
                        }
                    }
                });



            }
            dataBufferList.clear();
        }
    }).start();
```

Every time I encounter the issue, I notice that I will receive a log message:

**W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.**

However, I always call
**FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();**
Before I start to write on Firebase, and it always return the correct current user.

Besides, I want my APP to  be once sign-in, stay signed-in, so I don’t have to log in every time I open this APP. This my following code to achieve this:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (currentUser != null) {
        Log.d(LOGTAG,"onStart : current user :" + currentUser.getDisplayName());
    }
    else {
        Log.d(LOGTAG,"onStart : current user : null");
    }
    currentUserName = currentUser.getDisplayName();

}
```

Am I missing any steps here?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What has changed between being able to write and not being able to write anymore? Is there a lot of time inbetween? What is your datastructure and security rules?

Comment: I just noticed that I will get a log message if the writing fails : W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.

Comment: However, every time before I start to write data on Firebase, I call FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser(); to ensure that I'm staying logged-in and it always returns the correct user name, what is the right way to check if I'm still logged-in ?